# Error on delete trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

This trigger should delete a row from the parent table that is not deleted from the child table.  The error is in the image below.

My code attempt:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ProductDeleted ON Product 
for DELETE AS 
BEGIN 
     DELETE FROM OrderItem
     WHERE ProductID = (SELECT ProductID FROM DELETED)
END
```

help me please

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify it by adding a CASCADE DELETE hint on a foreign key constraint such as

```
 CREATE TABLE OrderItem
    (
     ID INT ,
     ProductID NOT NULL UNIQUE
        CONSTRAINT fk_Products 
           REFERENCES Products (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
    );
```

Since you already have a table, all you need to do is drop the constraint and recreate a new one.

```
ALTER TABLE OrderItem DROP
   CONSTRAINT fk_ProductID;

ALTER TABLE OrderItem ADD
   CONSTRAINT fk_ProductID
      FOREIGN KEY (ID)
      REFERENCES Product (ID)
      ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

What this means, is that , any time you delete a record from the parent table (Product), child records from (OrderItem)will be deleted as well, so you dont have to use triggers, unless if you want to do some recording.

---

If you are really insisting on using triggers then you can tweak it a little bit like this :

```
ALTER TRIGGER ProductDeleted  on Product
INSTEAD OF DELETE AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

/* First we are deleting referenced columns in OrderItem table */
DELETE FROM OrderItem 
where ProductID  IN (select deleted.ID /* Columns from product Table */ from deleted)

/* Now we are doing actual delete statement */
DELETE FROM Products where ID IN (select deleted.ID from deleted)
END
```

But once again you should consider using ON CASCADE DELETE, its much simpler to setup, easier to maintain and you can have only one INSTEAD OF trigger per table, so if you ever need to do something more meaningful you would have to change this one, and add extra overhead.

Comment: Yes I want the trigger to automatically delete the records associated with the product table when I delete a row from the product table please help me

Comment: See if this helps

Comment: Replace `where ID = (select deleted.ID from deleted)` with `where ID IN (select deleted.ID from deleted)`. The `deleted` virtual table will contain multiple rows for a DELETE statement that deletes multiple rows. The way you wrote it will result in a `subquery contains more than 1 row ...` error in that case.

Comment: It wont return an error, because it will delete multiple rows from OrderItem table, but it will do however if you pass multiple IDs to delete, so thanks for heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Add `SET NOCOUNT ON` as the first thing in the trigger's body (after `BEGIN`).